# Advanced Installer, difference between prerequisites

Tags: prerequisites, advanced-installer

I'm creating installer for my Mono- based project. As the application will be used on some older versions of Windows, I need to make sure, that at least .NET 4.0 framework is installed.

In the `requirements/prerequisites` tab I can find a list of predefined prerequisites, which the Advanced Installer supports by default. On the list there is also .NET 4.0 Framework included, this however is available in two versions:

- .NET 4.0 Framework
- .NET 4.0 Framework (web installer)

which version should I choose? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This higly depends on how you design your installer. If you want to be able to install your application **without** any Internet connection, than you should choose ".NET Framework 4.x" prerequisite.

All web prerequisites require an Internet connection to be able to download the real (full) installer.

Unless specified otherwise, all predefined prerequisites point to the standalone software installer. However, even for these prerequisites you have the option to choose between online *or* offline configuration when you select them for inclussion in your Advanced Installer project.